# Image in bottom right corner of cell in iTextPdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, cells

I'm struggling to find a way to place an image into bottom right corner of a cell in a table in iTextPdf.

I want to have image here:
[image]

I was playing with `IPdfPCellEvent`, but no luck so far.

Right now there's a bunch of newlines at the end, so the text wrapping/overflow isn't an issue.

Comment: "no luck so far" means what? No image at all? Image in the wrong corner of the cell? An exception? Which `IPdfPCellEvent` implementation you tried was nearest to the expected result?

Comment: No image at all. I'm not sure how to put image there in `CellLayout` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `IPdfPCellEvent` implementation like this one:

```
public class ImageDecorator : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    Image image;

    public ImageDecorator(Stream inputImageStream)
    {
        image = Image.GetInstance(inputImageStream);
        image.ScaleToFit(100, 100);
    }

    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
    {
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
        canvas.AddImage(image, image.ScaledWidth, 0, 0, image.ScaledHeight, position.Right - image.ScaledWidth, position.Bottom);
    }
}
```

Using it like this

```
using (Stream inputImageStream = new FileStream(imageURL, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create))
{
    ImageDecorator imageDecorator = new ImageDecorator(inputImageStream);

    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
    doc.Open();

    string loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.CellEvent = imageDecorator;
    cell.AddElement(new Paragraph(loremIpsum));
    table.AddCell(cell);

    cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.CellEvent = imageDecorator;
    cell.AddElement(new Paragraph(loremIpsum));
    table.AddCell(cell);

    doc.Add(table);

    doc.Close();
}
```

I get

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. That works.In the meantime my requirements shifted a little and now I have to also consider table splitting etc. so it's going to be whole new game. I'll also migrate to iText7.

Comment: *"I'll also migrate to iText7."* - in the long run surely a good decision. That being said, though, first thing to do might be to determine a more definite version of the requirements... ;)